# Can I use solder terminals on a PCB to power multiple AC devices?

Tags: arduino, pcb, pcb-design, ac, raspberry-pi

What's the most practical way to merge multiple AC Devices into one single cable?

I thought aboit it, and what if I solder multiple screw terminals on a PCB, fix them tight, attach a 50A AC fuse for safety, and solder and wire everything together with proper thickness cables? I think 6 AWG should be enough for the load that I plan to apply to it, around 50 amperes in total.

Will that work? Will the PCB burn at 50 amperes of load? There will be both AC and DC parts on that PCB.

More details on hardware:

Project requirements:

- One DC power supply for all DC components
- One AC aquarium water bubbler
- A Raspberry Pi 4
- Some buck converters
- Steppers (biggest current eaters)
- Sensors

AC Parts:

- [12V power supply](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Transformer-DC-12V-600W-Semiconductor/dp/B084224NZZ/ref=sr_1_6?crid=1OHKG9T60V600&keywords=12v+netzteil+50a&qid=1678048729&sprefix=12V+power+supply%2Caps%2C125&sr=8-6) - its load will consume most of the electricity
- [220 AC squarium air pump](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Measury-AIR60-Aquarium-Air-Pump/dp/B091CX6BMG/ref=sr_1_30?crid=3CNJ73Y7ZI9I6&keywords=aquarium%20sprudler&qid=1678041750&sprefix=aquarium%20bubble%2Caps%2C172&sr=8-30) maximum 5W of power consumption, more likely 3W.

Schematic (I'm new to Kicad and electronics in general so it may have some issues):

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: **ONLY** the bottom 3-screw terminal is connected to the mains. The rest of connectors represent: "hot" of the water air pump/ DC power supply, "neutral" of the water air pump/ DC power supply, and grounding in the case of the PS

[image]

Note:

- The AC sign was the only symbol I could find for "hot"

Comment: "the spiral size on schematics"?

Comment: @Hearth By that I mean this: https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/circuits-symbols-diagrams/wires-switches-connectors.php , more like a crossing over

Comment: The 12 volt power supply you link to will only draw about 3 Amp at 120 V - no need for giant wires or terminals.  Wires crossing without a dot already imply "no connection".  Your added X's only add confusion.

Comment: @PeterBennett My mistake, I added the 30A version, not the 50A, I corrected it.  Note I'm in Romania, Europe so we're at 220V. The power supply itself won't draw much current, but the motors, RPI and sensors will. In reality it shouldn't go beyond 25 amps, but with the spikes that can occur it's better to be safe

Comment: I was pointing out that the AC current will be quite low, so there is no need for large wire and connectors for it.  If the current on the 12 volt circuits will be 30 - 50 Amp, you do need larger wire for those loads.

Comment: KiCad has an exceptional  trace width calculator that includes temperature rise above ambient

Comment: @PeterBennett Oh, yes the Air Pump will draw very little current, but indeed, if the DC circuit will be the one drawing the 30-50 A, doesn't that mean that the AC cables that are powering the Power Supply, and the PCB Board, need to be thick as well? Since the current is still flowing from mains to the 12V P.S. to everything else? Let me know if I'm wrong with this and if yes, why?

Comment: The 12 volt power supply passes power (voltage times current) from its input to its output.  The output is 12 V at 30 A for 360 Watts. The AC input will therefore be 380 Watts (allow for a little inefficiency), or 220 V at 1.7 A.  I would try to keep the high current circuits off the PC board - do the high current wiring with wires and screw terminal strips if possible.

Comment: @PeterBennett most of the work I did was mostly on PCBs so far. How can I keep it off the PCB and still have all wires nicely organised? Another answer here suggests the same thing - staying away from the PCB - , but how can one do that efficiently? Do you have any tutorials on this? 

Also, by screw terminals do you mean this: bit.ly/3ygaaTE , or this: bit.ly/3SYl9L5. I suppose they are the same thing but the first one I mentioned can be mounted on a board, while the second can't if I got it right? There must be a way to fix the second ones on something too...

Answer (score 0):

Use a faston tab terminal block.

[image: faston terminal block].

This Hylec model has 3 screw terminals connected to a set of tabs for crimped on terminals. https://www.hylec-apl.com/Emech-Terminals-Accessories/Screw-to-Tab-Terminal-Block/FV110.html

Comment: Is it mountable on a PCB? I needed all the components to fit nicely on a custom designed one. Could you provide me a link to it?

Also, why do you prefer this one to the screw terminal ones? I do feel like the terminals would not be able to conduct the required 50A, though I'm not sure. Do you know any terminal that can be both soldered and handle that pretty big current?

Comment: This is a gadget that connects several faston tags to a screw terminal x3 (there are 3 separate buses L N Ground). Crimped terminals are much more reliable that soldering to a board.Don't mount of the PCB if possible.   But if you really want to go for a PCB use a "screw terminal strip" instead.

Comment: If you follow the correct procedures and guide lines no problem placing the terminals on a PCB. These rules depend on the location and environment. This is a relative common practice in the US on many appliances.